# Doubts about the resource function ClickRecurrenceMap2D

Tags: resourcefunction, resourceobject

It might seem weird that I'm the one asking this, but I honestly don't understand why the resource function [ClickRecurrenceMap2D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClickRecurrenceMap2D/) throws the following error:

```
ResourceFunction["ClickRecurrenceMap2D", ResourceSystemBase -> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/resourcesystem/api/1.0"][GMAttractor[X][{0.266, 1}], X, {1, 1500}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.003]]
```

[image]

I'm trying to implement `ClickRecurrenceMap3D` using Lukas Lang's [Locator3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Locator3D/) resource function, but I need to know what is going on with `ClickRecurrenceMap2D`.

Can someone guide me with this issue, please? :(

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!